# Google Play Developer Api - Cannot fully publish via python v3

Tags: python, api, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I'm using a service account in order to do this.

Everytime I run my script, my apk goes into the Artifact Library, rather than to my internal test track and the apk is not rolled out.

When I was using my script on v2, it would be set to the internal test track and would publish and rollout just fine.

What has changed?

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import argparse
import httplib2
import json
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type('application/octet-stream', '.apk')


def upload(package, service, apk, track):
    track = 'internal'
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        service, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'])

    service = build('androidpublisher', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    try:
        edit_request = service.edits().insert(body={}, packageName=package)
        result = edit_request.execute()
        print(result)
        edit_id = result['id']

        apk_response = service.edits().apks().upload(
            editId=edit_id,
            packageName=package,        
            media_body=apk).execute()

        print('Version code %d has been uploaded' %
              apk_response['versionCode'])

        track_response = service.edits().tracks().patch(
            editId=edit_id,
            track=track,
            packageName=package,
            body={u'releases': [{
                u'name': 'xx',
                u'versionCodes': [[apk_response['versionCode']]],
                u'releaseNotes': [
                    {
                        u'language': 'en-US',
                        u'text': 'helloworld'
                    }
                ],
                u'status': u'completed',
            }]}).execute()

        print(track_response)

        commit_request = service.edits().commit(
            editId=edit_id, packageName=package).execute()

        print('Edit "%s" has been committed' % (commit_request['id']))

    except AccessTokenRefreshError as e:
        print('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run the '
              'application to re-authorize')
        raise e


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--package', required=True,
                        help='The package name. Example: com.android.sample')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--service', required=True,
                        help='The service account json file.')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--apk', required=True,
                        help='The path to the APK file to upload.')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-t', '--track', choices=['internal', 'alpha', 'beta', 'production', 'rollout'], default='alpha')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    upload(args.package, args.service, args.apk, args.track)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It's always after you post that you figure it out. There is an error in the script. 
u'versionCodes': [[apk_response['versionCode']]] 
should be:
u'versionCodes': [apk_response['versionCode']].

Answer (score 0):

The script in the original post has an error in it.

```
u'versionCodes': [[apk_response['versionCode']]]
```

should read:

```
u'versionCodes': [apk_response['versionCode']]
```

Enjoy.